# invalid left hand assignment error?

Tags: javascript, invalid

```
function showNumber(number) {
  console.log(number)
  var earlierVal = document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText
  document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText = earlierVal + number;
}

function cleanCalculatorPanel() {
  console.log("cleanCalculatorPanel function called")
  document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText = "";
}

/*function calculateValue() {
  // 7+4
  console.log('caluclate value function called');
  var panelValue = document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText;
  console.log(panelValue.toString()); }*/

function plusNumber() {
   console.log('add value function called');
   var panelValue = document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText;
   var panelValueArray = panelValue;
   var beforeOperationVal = +panelValueArray[0];//5
  var afterOperationVal = +panelValueArray[1];//4
  console.log("beforeOperationVal"= beforeOperationVal);
  console.log("afterOperationVal" = afterOperationVal);
  console.log(parseInt(beforeOperationVal + afterOperationVal));
  document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText = parseInt(beforeOperationVal + afterOperationVal);//5+4=9
}

function minusNumber() {
   console.log('subtract value function called');
   var panelValue = document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText;
   var panelValueArray = panelValue;
   var beforeOperationVal = panelValueArray[0];//5
  var afterOperationVal = panelValueArray[1];//4
  console.log("beforeOperationVal"= beforeOperationVal);
  console.log("afterOperationVal" = afterOperationVal);
  console.log(parseInt(beforeOperationVal - afterOperationVal));
  document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText = parseInt(beforeOperationVal - afterOperationVal);//5-4=1
}

function multiplyNumber() {
   console.log('multiply value function called');
   var panelValue = document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText;
   var panelValueArray = panelValue;
   var beforeOperationVal = panelValueArray[0];//5
   var afterOperationVal = panelValueArray[1];//4
  console.log("beforeOperationVal"= beforeOperationVal);
  console.log("afterOperationVal" = afterOperationVal);
  console.log(parseInt(beforeOperationVal * afterOperationVal));
  document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText = parseInt(beforeOperationVal * afterOperationVal);//5*4=20
}

function divideNumber() {
   console.log('divide value function called');
   var panelValue = document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText;
   var panelValueArray = panelValue;
   var beforeOperationVal = panelValueArray[0];//5
   var afterOperationVal = panelValueArray[1];//4
  console.log("beforeOperationVal"= beforeOperationVal);
  console.log("afterOperationVal" = afterOperationVal);
  console.log(parseInt(beforeOperationVal / afterOperationVal));
  document.getElementById("calculatorPanel").innerText = parseInt(beforeOperationVal / afterOperationVal);//6/3=2S
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Right now, it's not clear whether this code is related to Salesforce or not. Please [edit] your question to indicate whether you are working in Visualforce or Lightning, and show the specific location of the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log("beforeOperationVal"= beforeOperationVal);
```

You can't assign a value to a string. Presumably, this is a typo. You would have wanted to write:

```
console.log("beforeOperationVal=" + beforeOperationVal);
```

Where "+" operates as string concatenation. You'll need to correct this problem each time it occurs in your code.